# Why is RedirectToAction including a literal from my route template in the URL it generates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, .net-core-2.0

I'm building a website using ASP.Net MVC and .Net Core 2.

When a user logs in my website, they are redirected to URL https://localhost/Games/Home
This is not what I want.

I would expect them to be redirected to URL https://localhost/

While debugging the application, I found out that the method that does the redirection is in the AccountController class generated by Visual Studio:

```
RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
```

My routes look like this:

```
                routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "games",
                   template: "Games/{controller}/{*tags}",
                   defaults: new { area = "Games", action = "Index" });

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I don't understand why the method RedirectToAction generates a URL that includes the literal "Games" from my route template.
I have an Area named Games, but I would expect the call to RedirectToAction to no match it.

I have already found a fix, though.
But I would still like to understand.

The fix replaces the first route by:

```
               routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "games",
                   template: "{area}/{controller}/{*tags}",
                   defaults: new {action = "Index" });
```

Comment: Do you have an area named `Games`? And if so,it would need to be `RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home", new { area = "" });`

Comment: the initial games route matches the action requested on redirect. You would need to be more specific `RedirectToRoute` with the "default" route name

Answer (score 1):

You can use RedirectToRoute() method. Create a new route. And specify the values for controller and action method. Once the user login to your application, call RedirectToRoute method with that route name as a parameter.